# AngularJS value won't change with setTimeout

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to change a scope variable after the page has been initialized.
I have a angular application with following code:

```
$scope.names = ['Jack'];
append_name = function(){$scope.names.push('Bob');}
setTimeout(append_name, 2000);
```

Tough I don't see the value change after the specified delay.
Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/FBa2fwb7js8pRNENNJof

Comment: Favor `$timeout` over `setTimeout`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609796/what-advantage-is-there-in-using-the-timeout-in-angular-js-instead-of-window-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: use the built-in `$timeout` service instead of `setTimeout`:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nh1jEhocRpXtD0rUTh4k?p=preview

Long answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9693933/1418796

Answer (score 0):

If you create code outside of angular you need to tell that you change something with $apply

```
$scope.names = ['Jack'];
append_name = function() {
   $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.names.push('Bob');
   });
};
setTimeout(append_name, 2000);
```

You can create handy higher order function to wrap your functions with `$apply`:

```
function ngWrap($scope, fn) {
    return function() {
        var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
        if ($scope.$$phase) {
            fn.apply(null, args);
        } else {
            return $scope.$apply(function() {
                fn.apply(null, args);
            });
        }
    };
}
```

this can be used like:

```
setTimeout(ngWrap($scope, function() {
    $scope.names.push('Bob');
}), 2000);
```

Also angular have $timeout that will handle this.

Comment: thanks. I had to write `socket.on('myevent', function(arg){$scope.$apply(function(){trigger_fn(arg)})})` for my [socket.io](http://socket.io) implementation. Any chance this could be simpler to read?

Comment: You can use `socket.on('myevent', ngWrap($scope, trigger_fn));` with function from my answer.