# Updating value on client side (angularJS) using setInterval()

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, setinterval

im using AngularJS for value calculator on the client side. I want to update the main value of this calculator every 5 minutes using setInterval().

My AngularJS code is:

```
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '../assets/sources.json'}).success(function(data)
   {
      $scope.values = data; // response data

      $scope.getSourceValue = function(){

         if ($scope.source == "test") {

            return $scope.values.test["last"]

         } else if ($scope.source == "test1"){

            return $scope.values.test1["last"]

         } else if ($scope.source == "test2"){

            return $scope.values["test2"]["last"]

         } else {

            return -1
         };

      } // getSource
    }
```

On client side:

```
<strong><h1> {{getSourceValue()|currency}}</strong></h1>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Sun Sep 14 2014, 01:40:03",
    "bitstamp": {
        "display_URL": "http://www.bitstamp.net",
        "display_name": "Bitstamp",
        "currency": "BTC",
        "last": 477.6
    },
    "btc-e": {
        "display_URL": "http://www.btc-e.com",
        "display_name": "BTC-e",
        "currency": "BTC",
        "last": 471.5
    },
    "bitcoinaverage": {
        "display_URL": "http://api.bitcoinaverage.com",
        "display_name": "BitcoinAverage",
        "currency": "BTC",
        "last": 479.23
    },
    "geeklab": {
        "display_URL": "http://ws.geeklab.com.ar",
        "display_name": "Geeklab",
        "currency": "ARS",
        "blue": 14.35
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of your json file ?

Comment: are you using `$scope.$apply()` in the `setInterval` to update the bindings? using `setInterval` takes you out of the angular digest. [AngularJS and Apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

Comment: No, I really don't know how to do it, I was trying with setTimeInterval for JS but didn't work with Angular (duh).

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS value won't change with setTimeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674590/angularjs-value-wont-change-with-settimeout)

Comment: Use $timeout and not setTimeout

Comment: Use $interval to have digest cycles fired automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution for someone else.
My approach:

```
angular.module('test', [])

   .controller('test', function($scope, $http, $filter, $interval) {



      var stop;

      if(!angular.isDefined(stop)) {
         stop = $interval(function(){


               $http({method: 'GET', url: '../assets/sources.json'}).success(function(data)
               {
                  $scope.values = data; // response data

                  $scope.svalue = 0;

                  $scope.getSourceValue = function(){

                     if ($scope.source == "bitcoinaverage.com") {

                        $scope.svalue = $scope.values.bitcoinaverage["last"]

                     } else if ($scope.source == "bitstamp.net"){

                        $scope.svalue = $scope.values.bitstamp["last"]

                     } else if ($scope.source == "btc-e.com"){

                        $scope.svalue = $scope.values["btc-e"]["last"]

                     } else {

                        $scope.svalue = -1
                     };

                  } // getSource


            });//  /success()


         }, 40000);
      }


}); /*Controller*/
```

Comment: You're redefining the $scope.getSourceValue in every ajax call. Move it to the outside scope and prefer using the 'this' aproach, put in $scope only if the function is shared with the child controllers.  
Other tip, the controller is the resposible for controlling the model<->view interation. Put the logic and data resources gathering into a service. :)