# AngularJS: How do I insert window.setTimeout into the scope function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.runTest = function() {
    var statesArray = ['Running', 'Complete', 'Rejected'];
    var rand = statesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * statesArray.length)];
    item.state = 'Running';
    console.log(rand)
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        item.state = rand;
    }, 6000);
};
```

`item` state change to `Running` is successful, but after that state won't change to a random as stated in the `window.setTimeout` function.

Where am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

you should use angular's [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

```
$timeout(function() {
    item.state = rand;
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 2):

`Windows.setTimeout` is out side an angular scope

you have to use `$scope.$apply()` to bind that value.

or use `$timeout`

refer this [What advantage is there in using the $timeout in Angular JS instead of window.setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609796/what-advantage-is-there-in-using-the-timeout-in-angular-js-instead-of-window-se)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` or `$timeout`, the problem here is that you are forgetting to call `scope.apply()` when using `setTimeout` to ensure that any changes to the scope will be reflected elsewhere.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        item.state = rand;
    });
}, 6000);
```

If you use `$timeout` you don't need to use `$scope.$apply()`:

```
$timeout(function() {
    item.state = rand;
}, 6000);
```

For more info regarding these two concepts, take a look at [What advantage is there in using the $timeout in Angular JS instead of window.setTimeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19609796/what-advantage-is-there-in-using-the-timeout-in-angular-js-instead-of-window-se#answer-19609851).