# Error: You should use the $timeout service instead of the default window.setTimeout method

Tags: angular, npm, eslint, typescript-eslint, angular12

I'm using the Angular 12 version in my project.

I've used setTimeout function as below:

```
setTimeout(() => this.document.location.reload(), 2000);
```

When I run `npm run eslintandfix` then I get an error like this

```
error You should use the $timeout service instead of the default window.setTimeout method angular/timeout-service
```

I've updated eslint scripts in my package.json as below:

```
"elint": "eslint . --ext .ts",

"elintandfix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
```

This is the state of my package.json EsLint plugins:

```
"eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.1",
```

I couldn't find any solution for this.
Kindly help me out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using AngularJS or Angular2+? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19609796/6513921

Comment: @MichaelD am using Angular2+ (Latest version of Angular 12) only. The above link which you shared for AngularJS.

Comment: If you make a quick google search of the `eslint-plugin-angular` you'll see that's it a set of rules for AngularJS, not Angular. Try switching to the `angular-eslint`.

Comment: @TotallyNewb You are correct! You saved me! Thank you so much!