# Hover on Image not working Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on website which uses Jquery and CSS3.
I have image and on hover i want to scale image. Hover works with CSS but i want it to via JQuery following code i have tried till now. Please help.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
   </head>
   <body >
      <img class="img-responsive" id ="thumbnail" src="my-image-src">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#thumbnail").on({
                 mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).addClass("scaleout");
                 },
                 mouseleave:function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("scaleout");
                 }
             },'img'); 
         });

      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
.scaleout {
    transform: scale(1, 0.80);
   -ms-transform: scale(1, 0.80);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0.80);
}
```

I also tried `hover()` method instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` in above script code

```
$(document).load(function(){
                $('#thumbnail').hover(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
                },
                function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('scaleout');
                });    
            });
```

Please help why hover not working.

Comment: `,'img');` to `);` in first method and not `$(document).load(` it's `$(document).ready(` in second method

Comment: Put the img into a div and declare a transition to its class.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a fiddle that works using code pretty similar to your second solution (use document.ready and no need for the removeClass function). https://jsfiddle.net/L5bj38me/

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbnail').hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
    })
  });
</script>
```

Update OP's issue is due to Angular see - [Run jQuery code after AngularJS completes rendering HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935766/run-jquery-code-after-angularjs-completes-rendering-html)

Comment: i tried same code but dont know why its not working when i put i css using :hover selector it works. My images gets rendered using angular js framework

Comment: @virendrao Make sure you don't have multiple images all with the same ID. Does my Fiddle work for you?

Comment: it works but when use in my script doesnt work though works through css

Comment: @virendrao your issue is due to Angular, see this post for a fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935766/run-jquery-code-after-angularjs-completes-rendering-html

Answer (score 0):

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdph34yh/1/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html >
           <head>
              <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
           </head>
           <body >
              <img class="img-responsive" id ="thumbnail" src="my-image-src">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
              <script>
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $( "#thumbnailtest" ).hover(    
                      function() {    
                        $(this).addClass("scaleout");
                      }, function() {
                        $(this).removeClass("scaleout");
                      }
                    );
                    });

              </script>
           </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'img' from event handler, 
Its work for me

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#thumbnail").on({
            mouseenter: function () {
                $(this).addClass("scaleout");
            },
            mouseleave:function () {
                $(this).removeClass("scaleout");
            }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried same code but dont know why its not working when i put i css using :hover selector it works. My images gets rendered using angular js framework

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, one solution is -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#thumbnail').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
    });
});
```

Here's another one -

```
 $("#thumbnail").mouseenter(function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
    });
```

Few more -

```
$( "#thumbnail" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
  });
```

Same output but with different approach -

```
$( "#thumbnail" )
  .mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('scaleout');
  });
```